# AVG of AVG, aggregate functions of subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, average, derived

This subquery produces the correct table. But now I want to get the average of the averages, and I'm getting an error "Missing FROM-clause entry for table "c"".

```
SELECT
   c.name,
   AVG(avgvalue)
FROM
(
SELECT
  c.name, 
  p.name,
  AVG(a."value") AS avgvalue
FROM answers a INNER JOIN survey_responses sr ON sr.id = a.survey_response_id AND a.question_id = 13
  INNER JOIN answers category_answer ON category_answer.survey_response_id =  sr.id AND category_answer.question_id = 264
  INNER JOIN answers_categories ac ON category_answer.id = ac.answer_id
  INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = ac.category_id
  INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = a.product_id
WHERE c.name IN ('Accounting') 
GROUP BY c.name, p."name"
HAVING count(p.name)>10
) as ProductAverages
GROUP BY c.name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are naming the `ProductAverages`, so your table aliases should reference it, not `c` - which can be used only in the inner query:

```
SELECT
   name, -- Here
   AVG(avgvalue)
FROM
(
SELECT
  c.name, 
  p.name,
  AVG(a."value") AS avgvalue
FROM answers a INNER JOIN survey_responses sr ON sr.id = a.survey_response_id AND a.question_id = 13
  INNER JOIN answers category_answer ON category_answer.survey_response_id =  sr.id AND category_answer.question_id = 264
  INNER JOIN answers_categories ac ON category_answer.id = ac.answer_id
  INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = ac.category_id
  INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = a.product_id
WHERE c.name IN ('Accounting') 
GROUP BY c.name, p."name"
HAVING count(p.name)>10
) as ProductAverages
GROUP BY name; -- and here
```